# Which game is this (RPG)?

Tags: game-identification

From a quiz app I have this screenshot. The question is just about the genre of the game which is an RPG, but there is no information about the name.

The quality is kind of bad, but maybe someone knows the game.

Google Picture Search brought no real results, maybe due to the writing in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot of game]

Comment: Looks very Uncharted-y, but I've never played them so I can't be for certain.

Comment: @Robotnik Sword on the back indicates otherwise; and it looks far too futuristic for any of the weaponry in any Uncharted game from 1-4

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The distinguishing feature in this image is the sword on the character's back (yes, it's a 2-handed sword). The design of its blade and handle unmistakably belong to [**Hayder's Razor**](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Hayder%27s_Razor_(Inquisition)) from [**Dragon Age Inquisition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Age_Inquisition).

Comment: Is Hayder's name derived from Arabic Haydar?